# how to add image inside button in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, styles

Hi guys I want to know how to add image inside button in asp.net

```
   <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" Height="27px" OnClick="Login_Click"  Text="Log In " Width="92px" EnableTheming="True" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you use just a `asp:ImageButton` Controls
like

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/Images/bullet.png"  AlternateText="No Image available" OnClick="mymethod" runat="server" />
```

OR

```
<button id="Button1" runat="server"><img src="Images/save.png" />Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regular button you can use the asp.net ImageButton and set the image url thats all you need'.

Answer (score 1):

You must know there are **3** type of buttons in Asp.net

`1)button`
`2)LinkButton`
`3)ImageButton`

here youcould use image button
like

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="40px" ImageAlign="Left" ImageUrl="~/Capture.PNG" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing to get image and text in one button

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Height="18" ForeColor="#606060">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/payslip.png" Height="18" style="float:left;"/>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Send Payslip" style="margin:0px 0px 10px 5px; float:left;"/>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Can't believe I'm the first person to vote this up.  This makes my page looks so much better.  Thanks for investing the effort into this.